# Use JS/Java to open pptx template and modify it

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, powerpoint, pptxgenjs

**TL;TR**

I need a pure js library to open a pptx template and edit some text fields.

**Full post:**

I am facing a problem and I am sure you will know the best aproach.

I am running a Spring Boot webpage which only has the home endpoint which returns the html template with js scripts.
In that page, the javascript runs to calculate some data and there is a button called "generate pptx".

At this point the best idea is to use the [pptxgenjs](https://github.com/won21kr/js-pptx) library but it has a problem:

> **Unimplemented features:**
>
> Importing Existing Presentations and/or Templates

What I really need is to open a template and modify some text there.

So my second choice would be the [protobi](https://protobi.com/landing/pptx) library. But it also has a big problem:

> **Cost:**
>
> $14,800 for perpetual OEM license for commercial use.
>
> $4,800 per year access for maintenance releases

Also we are not using node.js in our company.

So, any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask. But why do you want to do this with JavaScript. For Java there is Apache POI https://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Didn't really considered using the server side for this. I'll take a look.